# Quickfixj : difference between logout methods

Tags: java, quickfixj

will anybody please help me understand the difference between `session.logout` and `session.generateLogout`.

One can also create and send a logout message explicitly. How is that different from the other two?

Comment: From which API/Interface do you get these logout and generateLogout methods? Show some code.

Answer (score 3):

The logout method is the way to go. It will change the enabled flag which will trigger the `public void next()` method called by a timer. This will use the `generateLogout()` method to send the correct FixMessage(35=5). The generateLogout methods are all private except the one with no parameters which where changed to public with a changeset with no reason, so I guess this happens unexpected, since it is just a helper method for creating the message. Its the same for the logon you call `public void logon()` which changes the state and will trigger `public void next()` which calls `private void generateLogon()`.

[Session.java](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/master/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/Session.java)

Comment: i dont feel comfortable with logout as it stops qfixj from reconnecting to corresponding session. one needs to call logon in order start reconnection again.

Answer (score 1):

First of, by looking at the [Javadoc](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/javadoc/1.5.3/) for QuickFIX/J, one could argue it is kind of lacking the information needed for the methods you choose between.

My recommendation for you is to look at the [source code](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/master/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/Session.java) for this project and compare the methods (one of the benefits of open source software).

At a glance, see below for differences between the methods,

The `logout()` method only calls `setEnabled(false)`

while the

`generateLogout(Message otherLogout, String text, SessionStatus sessionStatus)`

calls all different kinds of things. For example it prepares a logout message, setting a session status and so on.

In summary, it seems the `generateLogout()` method is a more proper way to logout.

Comment: the version of qfixj i am using does not support generateLogout. what if i create and send a logout (35=5) explicitly. will that be ok?